# GCP Network Slow

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

The GCP network seems to be amazingly slow today.

Simply pulling images on my compute instance results in errors like “Get https://marketplace.gcr.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout”. 
Creating Kubernetes clusters (by gcloud ...) in my other project takes endless.

Please note, that the VM's itself (cpu, memory,..) are not overloaded, therefore I assume it to be a problem with the network.

I appreciate your help, since currently my production services are not accessible for most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

This may not the best forum for posting this kind of question. If you're having delays pulling images from gcr.io and creating clusters also show some delays, the root cause may be different.

If you suspect an issue with GCP's platform, you should contact GCP support as it may be a project specific issue. You can also track track public issues on issuetracker.google.com or check for known outages in status.cloud.google.com

EDIT: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers has information on how to file issues to issue-trackers. It is not specific for developers but users of GCP who want to either create new issues for product team to investigate or file feature ideas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip with issuetracker.google.com, however please note that it is just listed under "Google Developer" in https://console.cloud.google.com/support, which is a little bit misleading for this kind of issues.
The GCP support starts at $100/month, thats not affordable. Especially for issues at the providers end there should be a free option. 
The issuetracker.google.com - page does not show issues, however there were definitely issues yesterday.